# How to properly remove timestamp from date?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have a data set that originally has a time stamp like this:

```
'9/9/21 9:55'
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
'9/9/21'
```

However after using this code:

```
final$Date <- format(as.POSIXct(final$Date, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'),
                     format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

I end up with this:

```
'09/09/0021'
```

Comment: Maybe `strftime(strptime(Date, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"), "%m/%d/%y")`? Or just `sub(" .*$", "", Date)`?

Comment: Note since year is only 2 character use "%y" and not "%Y".  Also if you are only looking for the date part use `as.Date()` instead, saves some typing. `format(as.Date(final$Date, format='%m/%d/%y'),  format='%m/%d/%y')`

Answer (score 0):

`as.character()` works here. You might also be interested in the lubridate package.

```
> date.time <- as.POSIXct('9/9/21 9:55', format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
> as.character(date.time, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
[1] "09/09/21"
```

And in this specific case, `gsub()` is an even simpler solution, as Mikael Jagan suggested in a comment above. Note that there is a space before the '.', i.e., `gsub(' .+$', '', '9/9/21 9:55')`.

Comment: I think they want `"9/9/21"` and are not happy with `"09/09/21"`.

Comment: Oops, seems so. Looks like `gsub()` is the simplest solution here.

Comment: I am trying to do this for an entire column, specifically final$date. When I tried: final$Date <- as.POSIXct(final$date, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'), I received the error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Date, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 99454